# Mobile license key not valid

Tags: javafx, mobile, gluon

I ordered a mobile lincense key from gluon yesterday. So I added the Lincense annotation(@License(key="XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX")).
But when I run my application the log says that this license key is invalid. What Im doing wrong?

> Task :GluonApplicationTestApp:run
>   Mai 21, 2019 8:09:24 AM com.gluonhq.charm.down.Platform 
>   SCHWERWIEGEND: javafx.platform is not defined. Desktop will be assumed by default.
>   Mai 21, 2019 8:09:24 AM com.gluonhq.impl.charm.a.c.a$1 run
>   WARNUNG: Validation of license key XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX completed. License INVALID

Comment: Contact Gluon (?) support. This is a licensing / specific production configuration issue.. maybe the license was copied wrong? maybe it was never activated? maybe there is a license server (or however it works) issue?

Comment: I did contact gluon but I got no answer since 24h hours. I got some time issues. I need to fix it today, I did hope someone could help me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug at gluon's payment system. So they fixed it.